# What does provider mean when used in method declaration?

Tags: java, oop, provider

I've stumbled upon this piece of code:

```
public ServiceBuilder provider(Class<? extends Api> apiClass)
```

What does provider in this context mean?

edit:

This is the piece of code I found it in:

https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/scribe/builder/ServiceBuilder.java

Comment: IMHO this isnt a good name for a method when it throws questions like yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the name of the method.  The method `provider()` returns a ServiceBuilder.

Here's a link to the Java [Service Provider Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/SPI-intro.html).

Comment: See the link.  "Providers" are a thing in Java.  It's not a bad name.  Maybe "getProvider()" would be better but some folks don't care for the repeated "get" methods everywhere.

Comment: @markspace Not really, if you see the source it's a set so how getProvider could be better than provider? And anyway, if you see the code-example in the home page: https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java it's a very great name for a one-line code.

Comment: 'Provider' is a noun and afaik they shouldn't be used as names. `getProvider()` is even worse I guess because it would violate getters and setters convention in this case (getters dont have parameters). In addition, this method doesnt even return a Provider object but ServiceBuilder.

Comment: @MrPixelDream Right now, the name `provider` is a very great name. If you see the example https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java it was a great choice. I don't understand why you guys are saying that is a bad name without see the source (or at least, the example in the home page).

Comment: So in this context, ServiceBuilder defines the return type of this method? Similar to what void does? It means that this function returns a ServiceBuilder class object?

Answer (score 1):

> What does provider in this context mean?

Seems this class is used with `OAuth`. And it's a way to make an unique way to use multiple login from various services.

Example:

- Google: https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/scribe/builder/api/GoogleApi.java
- Facebook: https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/scribe/builder/api/FacebookApi.java

Your method seems to be used to create an instance of there apis based on what you pass.

```
provider(FacebookApi.class)
```

for Facebook and so on. Then a Service is build using all the data.

By provider he means who provide the access token (and auth data)